# How can I remove specific characters from a list and save as data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, text

I would like to

get a clean data set

without special characters

only with actual words

no numbers

that comes from a JSON file

.

```
 library(rvest); library(XML); library(dplyr);library(tidyr); library(purrr); library(rjson)

 url <- "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=Nike"
 nike_autocomplete <- read_html(url)
```

The output should look like this:

```
[1] "Nike" "nike air" "nike air max" "nike schuhe" "nike air force" "nike air max 97"
[7] "nike tn" "nike id" "nike air max 270" "nike vapormax" "nike pullover" "nike schweiz"   
[13] "nike 97" "nike off white" "nike air max plus" "nike winterschuhe" "nike schuhe damen" "nike huarache"  
[19] "nike shoes" "nike logo" "nike air max 90"
```

Thus, no empty things at the end

Comment: Your desired result doesn't look like a data frame. Is it one row with two columns? What are the column  names?

Comment: only one column, important would be to drop the values beginning of the first empty one.

Comment: will modify in a second

Comment: And are you sure your input is correct? When I run your `list <-` code I get a list containing a single data frame with 1 row and 10 columns... and you have values that are removed that that don't fit your criteria, e.g., why is `"tlw":false` not in the output? It's not special, numeric, special, or empty.

Comment: Is this from a JSON file? You might do better to improve the import process rather than try to clean up poorly-imported data.

Comment: Gregor, originally I was trying to clean up this: url <- "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=Nike"
nike_autocomplete <- read_html(url)
nike <- html_text(nike_autocomplete) %>%
    str_replace(., c("\r\n"), " ") %>%
    str_replace(., c("\ "), " ") %>%
    strsplit(., ",") %>%
    unlist() %>%
    gsub("[[:punct:][:blank:]]+", " ", .) %>% 
    str_trim()
    nike

Comment: Ok, I see. Any ideas how to improve that? (I did not know about how to improve it)

Comment: Make a reproducible example showing the source data in your question. FWIW, when I run the code you share in the question on the example you provide in the question, I get a very different output than what you show... please make sure your question is really reproducible.

Comment: Will change the question (thought I can provide a sipmlified example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you're trying to extract is in a JSON format, so you'll be much better off using a json-reading utility rather than trying to use regex. I like `jsonlite::fromJSON` for this.

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

url <- "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=Nike"
read_html(url) %>%
  xml_text %>%
  fromJSON() %>%
  extract(1:2) %>%
  unlist
#  [1] "Nike"                  "nike shox"             "nike shoes"            "nike air max"         
#  [5] "nike outlet"           "nike air force 1"      "nike basketball shoes" "nike vapormax"        
#  [9] "nike air max 97"       "nike id"               "nike store"            "nike stock"           
# [13] "nike air max 270"      "nike promo code"       "nike windbreaker"      "nike sweatshirts"     
# [17] "nike huarache"         "nike hoodie"           "nike cortez"           "nike sweatpants"      
# [21] "nike slides"
```